# Google API PHP and google spreadsheets

Tags: php, database, oauth-2.0, google-sheets, google-api-php-client

I am trying to use Google's oauth api to help me use google spreadsheets as a database, so when a users submits some information on my website a connection is made to my google account and the information is added to a specific google spreadsheet. I have tried setting this up using the google api PHP client library but the more I read into it the more confused I get on how to actually implement this. Can anyone help?

In the google developers console I have already created a client id, but for the api key would I need a browser or server key in order to add user submitted information to my google spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server key is for server to server communication and the browser key is for browser to server communication, so to make the request seamless you would need to use server to server key. You need to download the *.p12 file from google developer console and upload it to your server, then use it in your OAuth 2.0 calls.